# how to get rid of unnecessary anchor points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

I have applied pathfinder-minus front and that produces plethora of anchor points.

Is there any way to get rid of these without using plugins?
[image: ?]

Comment: Does *Object > Path > Simplify* work for you?

Comment: oh my god!!  didn't know about this feature!! Thankyou

Comment: @BillyKerr I know it's simple, but you should make that into an answer.

Comment: @WELZ I have done so now.

Comment: I gotta say that this i where Astute Graphics Inscribe Plug in is worth it's weight in gold -- removing anchors and *retaining* curves when doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try *Object > Path > Simplify*

You may need to adjust the settings to get the result you want. Just be aware that too much simplification may distort the image.